# Appium 1.2.0 The following desired capabilities are required but were not provided: deviceName

Tags: ios, appium

I am running appium on an IOS app, and try to open the Appium Inspector, it used to work fine until one day it suddenly failed with the error message:

The following desired capabilities are required not were not provided: deviceName

I've no idea why it suddenly didn't work, because thats the same Appium version and same .app file that I've been using.

Anyway, right now I have no idea how to set the desired capabilities; I don't even know which file to go to for setting that up; all I have is an .app file; does it require changing the source code of the app? Could any one provide some guideline regarding which file should I change and what value would deviceName expect?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is a poorly explained part of the appium documentation. It'll take me a bit to write up a decent explanation. Do you usually use the Appium.app to run the Appium server? or do you run it from command line?

Comment: @sheeptest I usually launch from Appium.app GUI

Comment: OK I highly suggest beginning to run the Appium server from the command line. I still use Appium.app for the Inspector, but the server capabilities don't get passed reliably through the GUI to the actual server.

Comment: People commonly see issues with deviceName and appPath even though they correctly set it.

Comment: @sheeptest actually the inspector is what I need to use... I didn't know we can start the insepector from command line... could you please tell me how to do so?

Comment: @sheeptest the problem is that I don't even know how to access/view/change the capabilities, so I can't even verify if these values are actually set or not...

Comment: The below answer tells you where the capabilities are in the Appium.app GUI. I suggest asking another question on Stack Overflow about running the Appium server from command line and using the Inspector with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting Desired Capabilities in the Appium GUI is done by clicking on the `Apple` icon for iOS-specific capabilities, or by clicking on the `Gear` icon for global capabilities.

The server capabilities and the desired capabilities are mixed in with eachother in the GUI.

Refer to the Appium [capability documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities) for information on each capability.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; When I click on the Apple icon on GUI, I don't see fields for setting capabilities though? I see Application section(for specifying the app path), Device Settings (for platform version, Force Orientation, etc. but not for deviceName), and Advanced section(for User Native Instruments Library, xcode path etc.). Could you please attach a screenshot on where exactly I should be looking at? Sorry for the dump question but I really cannot figure out.. Thank you!

Comment: all of those fields correspond to capabilities "Device Name" is the `deviceName` server capability. Yeah. I'll add an image.

Comment: but I can't find Device Name in the given screen.. I just uploaded an screenshot as well

Comment: after giving "force device" field, now the error is changed to: could not find automation.tracetemplate in in /Applications/xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Plugins/AutpmationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate

Comment: This is because you have Xcode 6. Appium GUI does not support Xcode 6 yet.

Comment: That explains everything!!! Xcode 6 automatically get updated during weekend and screwed up everything...... Thank you for helping me out!!

Answer (score 1):

For those who met the same problem in MAC:

1.make sure you specified the 'app' file

2.make sure you checked the "prelaunch application" option in settings.
 [image: prelaunch application]

3.and then restart the apppium server. focus on the error message (there must be plenty of text) and then adjust your settings

Answer (score 0):

According to the attached snapshot, enabling `Force Device` with name `iPhone` should work.